# How to find default proxy settings in Ubuntu

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, proxy, network-programming

I am implementing a program which will capture web browsers GET request, analyze it and then redirects it to the proxy server. To do this I need to find out what are the default proxy settings for my internet connection in UBUNTU. I am using C. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the proxy configuration stored by gnome in the GConf-2 keys :

- /system/http_proxy/use_http_proxy            boolean
- /system/http_proxy/use_authentication        boolean
- /system/http_proxy/host                      string
- /system/http_proxy/authentication_user       string
- /system/http_proxy/authentication_password   string
- /system/http_proxy/port                      int
- /system/proxy/socks_host                     string
- /system/proxy/mode                           string
- /system/proxy/ftp_host                       string
- /system/proxy/secure_host                    string
- /system/proxy/socks_port                     int
- /system/proxy/ftp_port                       int
- /system/proxy/secure_port                    int
- /system/proxy/no_proxy_for                   list
- /system/proxy/gopher_host                    string
- /system/proxy/gopher_port                    int

all of them are stored in the /home/user_name/.gconf/ directory. You can access to their value with a call on command line to [gconftool-2](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gconftool-2) or use the C bindings as [explained here](http://gnomejournal.org/article/68/gconf-configuration-system-concepts-for-developers) or [there](http://people.gnome.org/~newren/tutorials/developing-with-gnome/html/ch02s03.html).